# Is there some function to keep unique values in R dplyr with group_by?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

I have a `data.frame` (or `tiibble` or whatever) with an `id` variable. Often I made some operation for this `id` with `dplyr::group_by`, so

```r
data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise/mutate/...()
```

Often, I have other non-numeric variables that are unique for each `id`, such as the `project` or `country` to which the `id` belongs and other characteristics of the `id` (such as gender, etc.). When I use the `summarise` function above, these other variables ares lost unless I specify, either

```r
data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(across(c(project, country, gender, ...), unique),...)
```

or

```r
data %>%
    group_by(id, project, country, gender, ...) %>%
    summarise()
```

Is there some functions which detect these variables which are unique for each id, so that one does not have to specify them?

Thank you!

PS: I am asking mainly on `dplyr` and `group_by` related functions, but other environments like `R-base` or `data.table` are wellcome also.

Comment: Have you considered `ungroup()`-ing the data, or iterating over the variables you want to group by, e.g. with `map()`?

Comment: I am afraid the answer is no, there is no automatic detection of such variables. The solution which you already have are the way to go. 1) either mention them in `group_by`, 2) Use `across` + `unique` 3) Use `across` + `first` to keep them in the data.

Comment: Any desire to check the answers?

Comment: @mnist I have seen the answers. Thank you for yours.

Comment: Any desire to provide some feedbakc of any kind, like comment/upvote/accept?

Comment: @mnist My question was about the existence of a function. If I was to accept any answer, the better would be the comment by Ronak Shah above. Both answers don't provide an existent function, but build one and I do not want (I do not have enough time) to evaluate them, if they are efficient or not, etc. They are sure a nice and interesting work which could be useful in a future, for me or any other people looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it extensively yet it should do the job

```
library(dplyr)

myData <- tibble(X = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
                 Y = LETTERS[c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3)],
                 R = rnorm(6))
myData
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>       X Y          R
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1     1 A      0.463
#> 2     1 A     -0.965
#> 3     2 B     -0.403
#> 4     2 B     -0.417
#> 5     2 B     -2.28 
#> 6     3 C      0.423

group_by_id_vars <- function(.data, ...) {
  # group by the prespecified ID variables
  .data <- .data %>% group_by(...)
  
  # how many groups do these ID determine
  ID_groups <- .data %>% n_groups()
  
  # Get the number of groups if the initial grouping variables are combined
  # with other variables
  groupVars <- sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse) #specified grouping Variable
  nms <- names(.data) # all variables in .data
  res <- sapply(nms[!nms %in% groupVars], 
                function(x) {
                  .data %>%
                    # important to specify add = TRUE to combine the variable 
                    # with the IDs
                    group_by(across(all_of(x)), .add = TRUE) %>% 
                    n_groups()})
  
  # which combinations are identical, i.e. this variable does not increase the
  # number of groups in the data if combined with IDvars
  v <- names(res)[which(res == ID_groups)]
  
  # group the data accordingly
  .data <- .data %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(across(all_of(c(groupVars, v))))
  return(.data)
}

myData %>% 
  group_by_id_vars(X) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'X' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   X [3]
#>       X Y         n
#>   <dbl> <chr> <int>
#> 1     1 A         2
#> 2     2 B         3
#> 3     3 C         1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more advanced in application, but what you are looking for are linear combinations of your grouping variables. You can convert these to factors and then use some linear algebra.

You can use `findLinearCombos()` from `caret` to locate these. It takes a bit of work to get it all organized how I think you want it though.

Something like this may do the trick. I also have not extensively tested this.

**Packages**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(purrr)
```

**Function**

```r
group_by_lc <- function(.data, ..., .add = FALSE, .drop = group_by_drop_default(.data)) {
  
  # capture the ... and convert to a character vector
  .groups <- rlang::ensyms(...)
  .groups_chr <- map_chr(.groups, rlang::as_name)
  
  # convert all character and factor variables to a numeric
  d <- .data %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character), 
           across(where(is.character), as.factor),
           across(where(is.factor), as.integer))
  
  
  # find linear combinations of the character / factor variables
  lc <- caret::findLinearCombos(d)
  
  # see if any of your grouping variables have linear combinations
  find_group_match <- function(known_groups, lc_pair) {
    if (any(lc_pair %in% known_groups)) unique(c(lc_pair, known_groups)) else NULL
  }
  
  # convert column indices to names
  lc_pairs <- map(lc$linearCombos, ~ names(d)[.x])
  
  # iteratively look for linear combinations of known grouping variabels
  lc_cols <- reduce(lc_pairs, find_group_match, .init = .groups_chr)

  # find new grouping variables
  added_groups <- rlang::syms(lc_cols[!(lc_cols %in% .groups_chr)])

  # apply the grouping to your groups and the linear combinations
  group_by(.data, !!!.groups, !!!added_groups, .add = .add, .drop = .drop)
    
}
```

**Usage**

```r
data <- tibble(V = LETTERS[1:10], W = letters[1:10], X = paste0(V, W), Y = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 2), Z = runif(10))
group_by_lc(data, W)
```

**Result**

You can see how it added in all the other grouping variables. You can rework this all in other ways, the key part is building that `added_groups` list to find them.

```r
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   W, X, V [10]
   V     W     X     Y          Z
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 A     a     Aa    A     0.884 
 2 B     b     Bb    A     0.133 
 3 C     c     Cc    B     0.194 
 4 D     d     Dd    B     0.407 
 5 E     e     Ee    C     0.256 
 6 F     f     Ff    C     0.0976
 7 G     g     Gg    D     0.635 
 8 H     h     Hh    D     0.0542
 9 I     i     Ii    E     0.0104
10 J     j     Jj    E     0.464
```